# Ignore fetching if PFQuery is already running

Tags: ios, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

how can I ignore new fetching if one is already running. Here is one example of my code:
So if i call [self getParticipants] how to make sure to ignore if already running. The only solution I've got is to create BOOL property "inMiddleOfFetching" but I dont want to create anther BOOL property just for this. Is there a better solution?

```
- (void)getParticipants {
    PFQuery *participantsQuery = [self.participantsRelation query];
    [participantsQuery includeKey:@"client"];
    [participantsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects)
            self.participants = objects;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not simpler but it is better, you can use bolts to create a single task for the query, this way if it is called multiple times it will only run once but all calls will return the value at the same time.
Something like this:

```
 @property BFTask* task;
- (BFTask *)getParticipants {
if (!_task) {
    PFQuery *participantsQuery = [self.participantsRelation query];
    [participantsQuery includeKey:@"client"];
    _task = [participantsQuery findObjectsInBackground];
}

return _task;
```

}

Then to get the result:

```
[[self getParticipants] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if(!task.error){
        self.participants = task.result;
    }
    _task = nil; //if you want to run the query again in the future
    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: Oh very nice. I dont care if its not simpler. I want to do it the right way. Thanks a lot.